# Реализация базы данных

Tags: mysql

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать бд в данном случае. [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того, как добавили рецепт, мы можем посмотреть его ингредиенты (фото 2). Здесь и добавляются ингредиенты в рецепт.
Создал бд. В ней таблица recipt, ingredient, link. В таблице recipt, ingredient по id и name_r/i. В link - recipe_id и ingridient_id. Мне надо как-то связывать таблицы? Подскажите, как это реализовать.

Comment: Вы уже расписали правильную структуру таблиц для данной задачи. Не понятно в чем именно заключается вопрос

Comment: Не понимаю как связать таблицу  рецептов и ингредиентов. И нужно ли это вообще? Нужна ли мне таблица "link", в которой recipe_id и ingridient_id?

Comment: *Не понимаю как связать таблицу рецептов и ингредиентов.* С какого перепугу они должны связываться? вот в принципе никак не зависимые сущности.

Comment: Таблица link как раз обеспечивает связь, хранит информацию в какой рецепт какие ингредиенты входят

Comment: Mike, можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, как она обеспечивает связь? Не понимаю( Ну будет в recipe_id и ingridient_id записываться айдишники, а дальше?

Comment: А дальше пишите запрос с join со всеми 3 таблицами, или например только с Link и ингредиентами, если хотите по одному рецепту выбрать